# Interpolation polynomials and Vandermonde Matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I'm looking for a polynomial of degree $5$ such that: $p(-1)=1, p'(-1)=1, p(0)=3, p'(1)=2, p(2)=1, p'(2) = 4$

I want to show that there is no such polynomial by showing that the Vandermonde matrix associated to the system has a determinant equal to $0$.

Now I know that the Vandermonde matrix associated to the system is:

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 3 & -4 & 5 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & 12 & 32 & 86 \end{array} \right) $

The determinant is indeed $0$ (an therefore no such polynomial exists) But I don't understand how we came up with those **coefficients**.

Comment: In the matrix the bottom right entry should be $90$ instead of $86$.

Answer (score 1):

The general form of a degree $5$ polynomial is $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4 x^4 + a_5 x^5$. Now consider the equation $p(-1) = 1$, which is equivalent to

$$
a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 + a_4 - a_5 = 1 \iff (1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)\cdot(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) = 1.
$$

So the variables of the linear system are the coefficients of $p$, and the first row of the matrix corresponds to the vector $(1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5)$ at $x = -1$. You can use the same reasoning with the remaining equations to obtain the remaining rows of the matrix.