# proof of uniqueness of polynomial

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given $n+1$ points $(X,Y)$ in a plane such that no two points have same $x$-coordinates. Show:
$\exists ! f\in\mathbb R[x]$ s.t. $f(x)=y$

Comment: Why are you interested in this question and how did you try to solve it?

Comment: It follows inductively: two points for the line, three for a plane. Look up for Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2752386/721644

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015567/721644

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we are given points $(x_i,y_i), i=0,1,...,n$. Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^ny_i\dfrac{(x-x_0)...\hat{(x-x_i)}...(x-x_n)}{(x_i-x_0)...\hat{(x_i-x_i)}...(x_i-x_n)}$, where $\hat{x-x_i}$ means to exclude that term, then f(x) satisfies $\deg(f(x))=n, f(x_i)=y_i \;\forall i=0,1,...,n$.

Now, assume there is a n-th degree polynomial g(x) such that $g(x_i)=y_i \;\forall i=0,1,...,n$. Then consider $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Suppose h(x) is not a zero polynomial, then $\deg(h(x))\le n$. At each $x_i, h(x_i)=0,$ so h(x) can be written as $h(x)=k\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$ for some constant k. But then $\deg(h(x))=n+1$, and this is a contradiction. Hence $h(x)=0$ everywhere, and therefore $f(x)=g(x)$ everywhere. The desired polynomial is unique.